# Appending columns to the right of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

It's a rather simple question but i can't seem to work it out. I have the below code which appends two dataframes together:

```
final_dataframe = pd.concat([final_dataframe, df]) #append to final table
```

The only issue i have is it appends to the bottom, is there anyway to make it append to the right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you didn't use `axis`, pass param `axis=1` to concatenate the list of dfs column-wise.

Use:

```
 pd.concat([final_dataframe, df], axis=1)
```